# For whom did Sally Bugs work?

Tags: the-irishman

There is a little confusion in *The Irishman* about Sally Bugs. I mean whose man was he? Hoffa was controlling everything from prison (during his prison-time) and Fritz was an acting President of **Teamsters** and during this time we see Sally Bugs strangling a guy in the car and putting his body in garbage cutter machine so it seems as if Sally Bugs was working for Hoffa but just before the assassination of Hoffa (when he,Chuckie and Frank were in car) he answered, when questioned who was he,  *I'm with Tony*.

In the movie we never see Tony Pro with Sally Bugs and not even with Fritz.

Any personal thoughts are welcomed but they should have come from known references logically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Anthony “Tony Pro” Provenzano

---

> In real life, Anthony “Tony Pro” Provenzano was the International Brotherhood of Teamsters vice president for Teamsters Local 560 in Union City, New Jersey and Briguglio (Sally Bugs) was his strong arm man. Both in real life and the film, Briguglio wore thick glasses, making him appear more like an accountant than any sort of killer.
>
> In the movie, (Sally Bugs) **Briguglio ruthlessly kills a man upon Provenzano’s request all because the man gets more votes than him in a Teamsters election**, despite the pair being on the same side of the ticket and the man running for a different and lower office. Briguglio strangles him from behind in a car before putting his body through a wood chipper. And crazily enough, that is — sort of — true.
>
> The victim is a character based on real murder victim Anthony Castellitto, Local Teamsters 560's secretary-treasure, who Provenzano ordered killed. After Castellitto was strangled to death, Provenzano then appointed Brigulio as treasurer, according to federal court documents.
>
> [**Source**](https://www.oxygen.com/true-crime-buzz/the-irishman-who-was-real-salvatore-sally-bugs-briguglio)

Comment: I'm really thankful to you for your great answer. Apart from the question, can you please tell me if Tony Pro was a guy made by Hoffa or was he himself that good? I mean the way Fritz was made by Hoffa but then he became independent, something like that.

Comment: You can look up Tony on Wikipedia, lots of information there.